# Each array need an unique key in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I'm using React-Slick slider component for React JS, but I'm getting a warning that each array has to have an unique key.

I have an array inside of settings for the slider component. Settings are :

```
const settings = {
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 4000,
        responsive: [
            {breakpoint: 310, settings: {slidesToShow: 1, slidesToScroll: 1, autoplay: true, autoplaySpeed: 4000}},
            {breakpoint: 468, settings: {slidesToShow: 1, slidesToScroll: 1, autoplay: true, autoplaySpeed: 4000}},
            {breakpoint: 750, settings: {slidesToShow: 2, slidesToScroll: 1, autoplay: true, autoplaySpeed: 4000}},
            {breakpoint: 800, settings: {slidesToShow: 2, slidesToScroll: 1, autoplay: true, autoplaySpeed: 4000}},
            {breakpoint: 1200, settings: {slidesToShow: 3, slidesToScroll: 2, autoplay: true, autoplaySpeed: 4000}},
            {breakpoint: 1800, settings: {slidesToShow: 4, slidesToScroll: 2, autoplay: true, autoplaySpeed: 4000}},
            {breakpoint: 2600, settings: {slidesToShow: 5, slidesToScroll: 2, autoplay: true, autoplaySpeed: 4000}},
            {breakpoint: 100000, settings: 'unslick'}
        ]
    };
```

And the slider component where I use those settings is :

```
<Slider {...settings}>
      {this.cars()}
</Slider>
```

How can I map through those settings to give them an key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you might need:

```
...
render(){
   var Cars = settings.responsive.map.function(car, index){
      return(<div key={index}>YOUR CONTENT</div>);
   }
   return(
    <Slider {...settings}>
        {Cars}
    </Slider>
   )
}
```

I want to add that the second parameter of the map function can be used as a unique index which suits the reacts requested key attribute perfectly

Dirty solution:

```
...
render(){
   var counter = 0;
   var Cars = settings.responsive.map.function(car, index){
      counter++;
      return(<div key={counter}>YOUR CONTENT</div>);
   }
   return(
    <Slider {...settings}>
        {Cars}
    </Slider>
   )
}
```

Comment: I get now _Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `cloned2`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used._

Comment: I edited my answer. Try my "dirty solution" and tell me if it works and what the output is

Comment: I get the same warning.

Comment: Can you console.log the counter / index variable in each loop and check IF which loop gets executed twice? Other than a corrupt array I have no idea why the key value wouldn't be assigned uniquely in our case

Comment: The counter is incremented every time. Very strange.

Comment: Is it possible that your Slider component has an error and gets rendered twice somewhere? It seems to me that the problem lies somewhere else

Comment: It can be. Because I have two sliders on a page. I'm going to check it.

Comment: If my answer was right for the question you asked here please mark it as answered so that others will know :)

Answer (score 1):

For diff-algorithm to work correctly while comparing Virtual DOM, react needs all the list items to have unique keys so that it can identify and differentiate every component uniquely. The solution to this is to pass the index of the list as key as explained by @noa-dev above:

```
render(){
  var Cars = this.cars().map(car, index){
    return(<div key={index}>{car}</div>);
  }

  <Slider {...settings}>
     {Cars}
  </Slider>
}
```

Comment: I get now _Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `cloned2`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used._